# Vim, indentation not saving

Tags: vim, github

I just looked closely at some of the files I wrote in Vim and pushed up to Github from a local Git repo. Much of the indentation that appears in Vim is not transferring to Github. Is there a setting I need to change in .vimrc to make sure that my indentation from Vim is saved?

Comment: What makes you think your indentation didn't "make the transfer"?

Comment: You're right, the Vim indentation is not being saved to the file at all (I did a `cat` command for example). Would you have any idea as to what I could add to .vimrc?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Could you add an example or two to your question?

Comment: This sounds like you have tabs in your file which are not fixed with. Cat and github show them as 8 you might have `tabstop` set to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are possibly using tab characters. Tab characters can be interpreted differently depending on what editor you use, although it does seem strange they don't show up at all in the Github view.

I'd recommend changing tab characters to spaces. Within Vim you can specify settings with '**:**'.

To have them persist between sessions you'll need to store it in a file called [.vimrc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vimrc) (just you use '**set**' instead of '**:**').

> [To insert space characters whenever the tab key is pressed, set the 'expandtab' option:](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)

```
:set expandtab
```

You can then designate how many white space characters a tab inserts:

> [To control the number of space characters that will be inserted when the tab key is pressed, set the 'tabstop' option. For example, to insert 4 spaces for a tab, use:](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces)

```
:set tabstop=4
```

*I personally use tabstop=2*.

If that doesn't work, are you able to post your .vimrc containing whatever plugins/configuration you have, as well as a link to the file on github so we can see :)?

Let us know how you go!

Also re; using cat on the file - try:

```
cat -A [filename]
```

This should list hidden characters that perhaps weren't expected.

Comment: Switching to spaces instead of tabs seems largely to have fixed the problem. `cat -A` isn't an option on my machine though (OS X). `cat -e` did give me line breaks at least.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Looks like '-A' is a [shorthand option](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) that [Mac OS X doesn't provide](http://ss64.com/osx/cat.html). It's equivalent to `cat -vet` though, which should show you the characters you need.

Comment: That one neither. The only flags listed on the man page are   -b:  Number the non-blank output lines, starting at 1; -e: Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display a dollar sign ($) at the end of each line;  -n: Number the output lines, starting at 1;  -s:    Squeeze multiple adjacent empty lines, causing the output to be single spaced;  -t:     Display non-printing characters (see the -v option), and display tab characters as ^I.  -u      Disable output buffering.  -v:  Display non-printing characters so they are visible.

Comment: Sorry, I revised my comment, they are case sensitive - so it is `cat -vet`, not `cat -vET`. That should work according to the online manual I linked for Mac OS X, as well as your `man cat` output.